# is System.exit() on spring bean destroy valid?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

Recently I faced gracefull shutdown problem with Spring boot (1.4.7). To make long story short:

This lib register bean via Autocofiguration. This bean triggers System.exit call for some unscecified undocumented reasons. This cause deadlock when i'm trying to close spring context. This issue can be reproduced with following code:

```
@Configuration
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        SpringApplication application = new SpringApplication(App.class);
        ConfigurableApplicationContext context = application.run(args);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        context.close();
    }

    @Bean
    public Object someThirdPartyBeanIcantChange() {
        return new Object() {
            @PreDestroy
            public void tooSmartMethod() {
                //trigger some methods that will lead to
                System.exit(0);
            }
        };
    }
}
```

and content of maven's POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>TEST</groupId>
    <artifactId>context-test</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

As far as I can understand:

`context.close()` leads to calling `@PreDestroy` annotated method.
This leads to `System.exit(0)` which cause default spring's shutdown hook to close context itself which block on internal monitor already aquired by main thread which leads to deadlock.

So the question is: is this a valid behaviour to call `System.exit` in destroy methods?

And any ideas how could I overcome such deadlock if springs shutdown hook (or other similar one) is necessary (except for changing bean behaviour of course)?

Comment: *"is this a valid behaviour to call `System.exit` in destroy methods?"* Absolutely not. No bean should interfere with the JVM lifecycle.

Comment: I don't know much about Spring, but you might be able to install a custom SecurityManager that throws an exception when this bean will call `System.exit(0)`;

Comment: you can try creating a wrapper around that bean with the same interface and you can manage the other beans lifecyle via your wrapper. Wrapper can be a decorator, extension, aop whatever you feel like.

Comment: Yes you are right. I had the same problem. Spring is blocking the internal monitor. As an alternative you can try Runtime.getRuntime().hatt(1); This call bypasses shutdown hooks.